# jQuery not replacing html button with text for more than 1 user

Tags: php, jquery

I have this piece of code written in jQuery and PHP:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".vote<?php echo $pid; ?>").click(function(){
  $("span.vote_box<?php echo $pid; ?>").html("you have voted");
  });
});
</script>
```

But it doesn't seem to work. What it is supposed to do is to print "you have voted" in the position of a button which users can use to vote some post with. It reacts ok in the beginning but when i log on as a different user the button stays intact and doesn't get replaced.

Here is the PHP and HTML part:

```
<?php
echo '<span class="vote_box'.$pid.'">';
echo '<input type="button" class="vote'.$pid.'" name="vote" value="vote"/>';
echo '</span>';
?>
```

NOTE: I am using an AJAX request to insert the vote to the database so practically all I want jQuery to do is replace the button with text

Any help? I am new to jQuery so I figure the "html" method I am using could be wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using Javascript to do this? Better is to have PHP simply output the appropriate text/button when the page is generated.

Comment: @MarcB i'm sorry i dont think i got the question. the button is there for a user to vote and when he votes i want it to be replaced with the text

Comment: Your code looks correct, do you have a live page we can take a look at? My guess it's an issue with the `$pid`, but would have to see the html and js to be sure.

Comment: @swatkins unforunately not. but imagine it as a fb-like "like" system, in which when a user "likes" something it is automatically replaced with "unlike". and each user can do that

Comment: Is the vote going out via ajax? Then this code would make sense.

Comment: You might have a typo in the code, it looks as if your button click selector: `$(".vote<?php echo $pid; ?>").click(function(){` is looking for the class of `.vote35` (or something like that), but your button only has a class of `.vote`

Comment: @MarcB yes. the vote is being sent via ajax. i use jquery just to replace the button with text to inform each user whether he has voted or not

Comment: Can you show us the generated html/js from the page?

Comment: @swatkins it's really messy to isolate this particular part. i wish i could.

Comment: Wow, OK. could you at least tell us what the generated class names are for the span and button? You're asking for help, but are reluctant to give us what we need to help?

Comment: When logged in as another user, do you get any JavaScript errors when you click the button?  Also, what datatype is the `$pid` variable?

Comment: @swatkins it really is difficult for me to isolate the working parts of this. of course i'm not reluctant

Comment: @Farray no i don't get any errors and the $pid is a string

Comment: @gianniskpf Why don't you provide the HTML for the entire page. I'm sure we can decipher it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating things in your code. Assuming you have the following html:

```
<span class="vote_box1">
  <input type="button" class="vote1 vote" name="vote" value="vote"/>
</span>
<span class="vote_box2">
  <input type="button" class="vote2 vote" name="vote" value="vote"/>
</span>
```

and the following javascript:

```
$(function(){
  $('input.vote').click(function(e){
    $(this).parent().html('You have voted!');
  });  
});
```

Everything should work fine, as seen in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thomas_peklak/gm5Pe/). If you still want to use your code, you have to start to debug.

From my experience if something does not work in jQuery and fails silently (this means no exception thrown), then the selector is not right. You can easily debug this with the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert('Button: ' +  $(".vote<?php echo $pid; ?>").length);
  $(".vote<?php echo $pid; ?>").click(function(){
    alert('Votebox: ' +  $("span.vote_box<?php echo $pid; ?>").length);
    $("span.vote_box<?php echo $pid; ?>").html("you have voted");
  });
});
</script>
```

This should alert:

- Button: 1
- Votebox: 1

If on of these values is 0 you know that the selector is false.

Comment: mr, you have just upgraded me to jquery noob level 1. thanks A LOT! that actually worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

Since your $pid variable is a "string", there is a good chance that you have illegal characters interfering with your jQuery selector.  This is why it may be valid for one user and not for another - Single-word, alpha-numeric words will work fine as a $pid in this scenario, but other variations may not.

For example:

$pid is 'admin':

```
<span class="vote_boxadmin">...

$("span.vote_boxadmin").html(...);   //valid selector
```

$pid is 'some user':

```
<span class="vote_boxsome user">...

$("span.vote_boxsome user").html(...);  //looking for <user> child of span.vote_boxsome
```

Another interesting secnario is when $pid is an email address.  `<span class="user@example.com">` is valid HTML5, but jQuery won't select it properly.

Without seeing your actual JS/HTML output, there is no way to know for sure.  This is where I would start looking though.